# Compiling and Running MFC Applications with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, compilation

I was wondering if anyone can provide a detailed explanation on how I can compile and execute a C++ MFC application in Visual Studio 2008 given that I already have a .h and .cpp file only.

I couldn't find a decent and up to date explanation anywhere and when I try to create a plain MFC project in VS08 I get a bunch of xxx.h xxxDoc.h xxxView.h files, I try and replace those files with my own .cpp and .h files but i get a ton of errors when I run it.

So just to summarize, how do I compile and run my MFC project's .h and .cpp files in Visual Studio 2008 and create an .exe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears that you're not very familiar with these kinds of projects. I suggest that you study in general the Document/View pattern, how its structured and why, and that will give you the tools to incorporate your h/cpp files without a problem. Alternatively, you could uncheck the box next to Document/View, and have a simpler application structure. Your choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [Creating an MFC Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9es9d1k4.aspx)

This tutorial may help you as well: [Introduction to MFC Applications](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/Lesson02.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do, but deleting the files the wizard creates is not a good idea. They are there because you told it to put them there (by selecting MFC-SDI/MDI), so they are necessary for the basic initialization and such.

If you don't need the Doc/View architecture, you can create a Dialog Based application. Or, you can even use an MDI or SDI app, and not use the Doc and the View, but if you want to delete them you'll have to make sure there are no references to them. What you cannot delete is the "MyProject.cpp" (where the CWinApp derived class lays), which does the initialization of the application.

Another option is to create a Console application with MFC support. To do so, you have to select "Win32 console application" in the wizard and then check "Add headers for MFC".